# Are there any pop songs in F minor that use D(le) in the melody of the song?

Tags: piano

Are there any pop songs in F minor that use D(le) in the melody of the song? If so, I would like to know.

Comment: Welcome! This sort of question [isn't covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But the answer is "Surely countless ones." [Dorian mode](https://www.reddit.com/r/musictheory/comments/euygsx/your_favorite_songs_pieces_in_dorian/) would have this D natural; melodic minor would have it along with E natural; and many songs use notes outside of the "scale" as chromatic ornaments, or in chords "borrowed" from other tonalities (e.g., Fm, G7 (containing a D natural), C).

Comment: What does "D(le)" mean?

Comment: @Jos In moveable-do solfege the sixth scale degree is “la.” There’s also a system for representing chromatic alteration, in which the lowered version would be “le.” of course this gets a little confusing, because in this question the sixth degree has actually been raised from its natural-minor version. To make matters even more confusing, the system set up by Kodaly used “la-based minor” anyway, in which the relative natural minor keeps the same syllables for each pitch as major, so the minor scale starts on la.

Comment: @Jos Actually, maybe I’m over complicating things in my confusion. [Looks like](https://open.library.okstate.edu/musictheory/chapter/minor-scales/) the solfege for a natural minor scale would  normally use LE, so a raised 6thdegree would just be LA.

Comment: thank you guys!

Comment: @AndyBonner ah, that "Le"'. I have heard of it, but never seen it used so casually.